# Custom Gutenberg Block and unfiltered_html capability

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, block-editor

This is more a "am I understanding this right" kind of question:

When I create a custum Gutenberg Block that should be used by an user of role Editor(which has no unfiltered_html capability on a multisite), I am limited to whatever html wordpress allows this user to post.

Example:

My save function has jsx like this:

```
<p style={myStyles}>{props.attributes.text}</p>
```

which gets rendered to

```
<p style="opacity:0.5">Hello World</p>
```

This would get filtered out and the block would not work.

Additionally, this Block would work for a Super-Admin and when he creates a post using this block and an Editor comes in later to adapt it, it would break the block, because it expects the mark-up that was filtered out.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of using RichText Component inside save function is -

```
     <RichText.Content
            tagName="p"
            style={ styles }
            className={ className ? className : undefined }
            value={ content }
            dir={ direction }
        />
```

See, how this core [paragraph block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/paragraph/index.js#L263) is doing it. Instead of using normal HTML use RichText Content on text fields